# How do I use Node.JS modules on my site?

Tags: node.js

Okay, let me preface this by saying I am a complete noob when it comes to Node.

I have a Node module, Typed.js, that I want to use on my site, but I'm not sure how. I don't think it'll work out the box since Node is a server-side tool, and you import stuff from the Typed.js package.

Comment: First off, you can only use node.js modules in the browser that don't use functionality that is server-side only.  Modules such as `fs`, `http`, `net` would be off limits for browser usage.  Then, there are lots of different strategies for sharing code between node.js and browser, everything from using a loader in the browser that can handle node.js module definitions to using a packing tool like webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrapper your code up like this

```
(function(exports){

    // your code goes here

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this['typed']={}: exports);
```

Then in your client side

```
<script src="typed.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(typed.your-function());
</script>
```